# How to bind several listeners to an element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Something like this: `v-on:click="count,handle"`

I tried to ask this question in Vue gitter channel, but the only advice I got it's to use one listener which executes others.

If it's the only way to do it, I would like to know why. Is it a bad practice to have more than one listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. I have just read official docs (yeah, I know, shame on me) and found there such phrase:

> Similar to the restrictions on inline expressions, event handlers are
>   restricted to one statement only.

http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html

But I'm still curious to know why is it so.